# Custom Attribute Panicked with enum_dispatch macro

Tags: rust

I'm getting a `Unsupported Argument Type` error when using `#[enum_dispatch]`. My code below very closely follows the [example from the docs](https://github.com/ethanhs/enum_dispatch/blob/master/tests/compiles.rs), so I'm not really sure what the issue could be as this error message is very opaque. Any thoughts on what the cause could be or how I could get a more detailed error report? I can run the example fine, so I don't think it's an issue with the compiler.

```
enum_dispatch = "0.3.5"
undo = {version = "0.46.0", features = ["colored"]}
```

```
use undo::{Action, History, Merged};
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;

pub struct AppState{
    names: Vec<String>
}

#[enum_dispatch(AppActionTest)]
pub trait AppAction{
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.apply(target)
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, _: &mut AppActionTest) -> Merged {
        Merged::No
    }
}

pub struct AddMask;
impl Action for AddMask{
    type Target = AppState;
    type Output = ();
    type Error = String;
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>{
        dbg!("APPLYING ADD MASK");
        Ok(())
    }
    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>{
        Ok(())
    }
    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.apply(target)
    }
}

#[enum_dispatch]
pub enum AppActionTest {
    AM(AddMask)
}

fn main(){
    dbg!("running");
}
```

gives error statement:

```
error: custom attribute panicked
  --> src\main.rs:41:1
   |
41 | #[enum_dispatch]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: message: Unsupported argument type

error[E0412]: cannot find type `AppActionTest` in this scope
  --> src\main.rs:19:33
   |
19 |     fn merge(&mut self, _: &mut AppActionTest) -> Merged {
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

I created a [repo](https://github.com/wyhinton/enum_dispatch_issue) with this code if you'd like to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://gitlab.com/antonok/enum_dispatch/-/issues/44) and the repo owner gave me a response. Looks like the `_` in `AppAction::merge` is responsible for this. Instead, try:

```rust
#[enum_dispatch(AppActionTest)]
pub trait AppAction{
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.apply(target)
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, _unused: &mut AppActionTest) -> Merged {
        Merged::No
    }
}
```

EDIT: This issue should be fixed in versions `enum_dispatch 0.3.6` and greater now.